# How to manage Presto query session variables using REST API?

Tags: rest, session, presto

I am using the Presto REST api to query the database, but all my sessions appear to be ephemeral. For example, if I do something like

`query_presto('set session columnar_processing = true')
query_presto('show session')`

Despite setting the column_processing variable in the first query, the second query will show that column_processing is still the default value of false.

I read somewhere that

> Presto maintains sessions for each authenticated user. This session
>   expires if no new requests are received within the timeout period
>   configured for Presto.

However, I can't find this configuration anywhere in the code nor documentation.

My question is how do I maintain a database session using the RESTful API?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After too much time digging around, I found that there is a header `X-Presto-Session` which you can set comma separated variables, ie

`curl --data "show session" http://127.0.0.1:8889/v1/statement/ --header "X-Presto-User: myuser" --header "X-Presto-Schema: myschema" --header "X-Presto-Time-Zone: UTC" --header "X-Presto-Catalog: mycatalog" --header "User-Agent: myagent" --header "X-Presto-Session: session_variable_1=900,session_variable_2=true"`

Despite what the doc says, I don't think there is a way for Presto to remember session variables set in previous executions. I have to locally cache them in my program and pass them all every execution.

Comment: Hey @wonton, thanks for self-answering this - this was a lifesaver!